# How to roud off a String value "5571.329849243164" in android

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I'm getting below error while converting String array to Long array.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "5571.329849243164". How to round off this value like 5571.

Comment: A long is an **integer** number: it **doesn't accept decimals**. If the original value is a string, then you can simply use the `split` function and take the first string found in the returned array. `myStr = myNumber.split(".")[0];` Then convert it to long.

Comment: Where is the code of round off ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//try this way, hope this will help you...

String value = "5571.329849243164";
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,""+Math.round(Double.parseDouble(value)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @ Haresh.. I tried to upvote but error msg displays as "Vote up requires 15 reputation"... sorry dude

Answer (score 1):

Use this

String.format("%.2f", d)

Answer (score 0):

round(Double value)`

see here

```
String string = "5571.329849243164";

    Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(string);

    tv.setText(Math.round(value1) + "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to convert a String representing a floating point value to an Integer with rounding, not truncation. Perfectly reasonable.

Two choices.

1. Convert the string to a Double first (`Double.valueOf()`), then convert to Integer (`intValue()`) using a rounding algorithm. Usually it's enough to just add 0.5 to the Double.
2. Round the String using string operations, then convert to Integer. Split the string at the first ".", convert it to Integer (`getInteger())`. If the digit after the "." is in the range 5-9 then add one.

I'm sure you can write the code.